# Crear enlace de descarga PDF en React js

Tags: reactjs, pdf, download

Estoy creando mi primer portfolio en React js y estoy intentando colocar un enlace de descarga de mi CV.

Este es el código:

```
<div>
      <ScrollLink to="mywork" smooth={true}>
        <button className={`btn`}>
            <a href={pdf} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">Click here for my pdf</a>
        </button>
      </ScrollLink></div>;
```

el archivo esta importado:

```
import pdf from '../../../../src/PDFdowload/Grilli-Ignacio-CV.pdf';
```

Funciona en parte ya que al cliquear aparece esto en el navegador, es como que linquea, pero no se realiza ninguna descarga:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

también probé agregando `target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"` a la etiqueta ya que al darle clic derecho funciona (no como me gustaría pero es una alternativa) y abre una ventana nueva con el PDF. Es decir, una alternativa sería que al dar clic izquierdo se abra una nueva ventana, para ello el target. Pero por el momento hay que hacerlo con el boton izquiero y sería contra-intuitivo.

Espero me puedan ayudar, desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yo también tuve el mismo problema y lo pude solucionar añadiendo el atributo `download` al target, así:

- Puedes encontrar más info aquí: https://qastack.mx/programming/11620698/how-to-trigger-a-file-download-when-clicking-an-html-button-or-javascript

```js
<div>
  <ScrollLink to="mywork" smooth={true}>
    <button className={`btn`}>
      <a href={pdf} target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" download="nombre_pretendido_del archivo.pdf"> 
      Click here for my pdf 
      </a>
    </button>
  </ScrollLink>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente!! me funcionó correctamente!! muchas gracias!